# Why can an object of an interface type be assigned to a foreach loop variable of a concrete type?

Tags: c#, interface

The program I am trying to modify has this function:

```
public void AddSegments(List<ISimRecipeSegment> listSegments)
{
    foreach (CSimRecipeSegment seg in listSegments)
    {
        if (seg.IsHeatingSegment)
            SetHeatSegment(seg);
        else // Cooling segment
            SetCoolSegment(seg);
    }
}
```

CSimRecipeSegment is defined like this:

```
public class CSimRecipeSegment : CSimObject, ISimRecipeSegment
```

Why is it possible to assign an object of type ISimRecipeSegment to a variable of type CSimRecipeSegment?  There's no guarantee that the object in the list is actually a CSimRecipeSegment.  It could be any other type that implements the ISimRecipeSegment interface.  Couldn't it?

Comment: `foreach` is special in that it allows you to do that and hope for the best, legacy from back before generics were introduced. It allowed you to do `foreach (int value in ArrayList)`. It will crash runtime if the types doesn't match, however.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen what happens if it isn't a CSimRecipeSegment, is seg == null?

Comment: @Rob: It behaves like a regular cast - `null` can be cast to any reference type, but something that's non-null and of the "wrong" type will cause an exception.

Comment: See also [this @EricLipper post](https://ericlippert.com/2013/07/22/why-does-a-foreach-loop-silently-insert-an-explicit-conversion/).